# List radio buttons beneath eachother inside a Table

Tags: html, css, radio-button

I'm trying to get a list of radio buttons listed below eachother inside a 
table data. Is this possible?  Here is my current code

```
            <table>
            <tr>
                <td> Voornaam </td>
                <td> <input type="text" class="profiel_inp"> </td>
                <td> Studentennr </td>
                <td> <input type="text" class="profiel_inp"> </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td> Achternaam </td>
                <td> <input type="text" class="profiel_inp"> </td>
                <td> Klas </td>
                <td> <select class="selectinp">
                      <option value="volvo">V1L</option>
                      <option value="saab">V1C</option>
                      <option value="mercedes">V1E</option>
                      <option value="audi">V1F</option>
                    </select> 
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td> Adres </td>
                <td > <input type="text" class="profiel_inp size2"> </td>
                <td> Studierichting </td>
                <td > SNE <input type="radio" class="profiel_inp" name="Studierichting"> </td>
                <td > BIM <input type="radio" class="profiel_inp" name="Studierichting"> </td>
                <td > SIE <input type="radio" class="profiel_inp" name="Studierichting"> </td>
                <td > SNE <input type="radio" class="profiel_inp" name="Studierichting"> </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td> E-mail </td>
                <td> <input type="text" class="profiel_inp"> </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td> Telefoonnr </td>
                <td> <input type="text" class="profiel_inp"> </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td> Geslacht </td>
                <td> Man<input type="radio"  name="geslacht" class="profiel_inp"> 
                Vrouw<input type="radio"  name="geslacht" class="profiel_inp"> </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td> Geboortedatum </td>
                <td> <input type="date" class="profiel_inp"> </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
```

with the CSS :

```
table {
width:100%;
margin-top:25px;
margin-bottom:25px;
}

input[type="text"], input[type="date"], .selectinp {
    min-height:30px;
    border:1px solid black;
    padding:5px;    
    width:75%;
}
table tr {
    padding-bottom:5px;
}

.size2 {
    min-height:60px!important;
}
```

So ive got a table with a left and right side. Now on the left side is pretty basic but the right side has to contain a list of 4 radio buttons listed beneath eachother!

Comment: your table layout is invalid, you have a mismatch between the number of columns in each row.  You should also not use tables for layout purposes - which you seem to be doing

Answer (score 0):

You could add them to a fieldset and wrap them in labels. Then in css set label display to block.

html

```
      <td name="Studierichting">
        <fieldset>
          <label><input type="radio" class="profiel_inp" name="Studierichting">SNE</label>
          <label><input type="radio" class="profiel_inp" name="Studierichting">BIM</label>
          <label><input type="radio" class="profiel_inp" name="Studierichting">SIE</label>
          <label><input type="radio" class="profiel_inp" name="Studierichting">SNE</label>
        </fieldset>
```

css

```
label {
  display:block;
}
```